# Display a new popup after pressing reset button by closing old popup and show the same form freshly

Tags: php, javascript

I have a pop up window,which is displaying form which can contain previous some form details or new form.When i press a button it should reset to the new form by closing the active dialog window.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you are wanting to accomplish? It would also help if you could post some code examples so that we are able to understand what you are referring to.

Comment: `<button onclick="window.close()">Close</button>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onClick="changeDiv()"`

```
function changeDiv() {  <br>
var div = document.getElementById("name_of_form_to_be_replaced"); <br>
if(div) {  <br>
div.innerHTML = (call to the same function to get the New form); <br>
} 
}
```